# You don't have permission to access / on this server WAMP server on Windows 7 after setting up vhost

Tags: apache, wamp, vhosts

I get this error : You don't have permission to access / on this server.

vhost plugin enabled in apache webserver and inside the vhost i have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myfiles"
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/domain.com.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain.com" common
 </VirtualHost>
```

works on my laptop not on my tmp-server running windows7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First when you setup vhosts it is best to also create one for localhost.

Also you need to tell apache from which ip addresses it is allowed to accept connections from for each of the vhosts.

So try this

```
# Should be the first VHOST definition so that it is the default virtual host
# Also access rights should remain restricted to the local PC and the local network
# So that any random ip address attack will recieve an error code and not gain access
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@homemail.net
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>
        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/myfiles"
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com
    ErrorLog "logs/domain.com.log"
    CustomLog "logs/domain.com" common
    <Directory  "C:/wamp/www/myfiles">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
            Require ip 192.168.2
        </IfDefine>

        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally if you mean you enabled `vhost_alias_module` in Apache, you do not need that in order to use Virtual Hosts like this, so you should disable it.

To activate the `extra\vhost-httpd.conf` changes, dont forget to uncomment this line in the `httpd.conf` file, so that this extra file gets included.

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: I'm using vhost_alias_module, so i can have all my vhosts in that file (extras/vhosts), so i guess there must be some updates

Comment: Disable vhost and add this direct to the http.conf file work! so i guess its OK, but i cant get the extras/vhost-conf work.

Comment: I tryed this, and moved the conf to that, without no luck, must be my server that disallows me to use vhost. Alltough your example works fine with non use of the vhost file! thx!